# std::string to rapidJson object conversion

Tags: json, string, parsing, stdstring, rapidjson

I was trying to convert one std::string to rapidJson object in below format

```
  { 
     "data":{

               "value": "AB1234"
            }
  }
```

I have tried

```
rapidjson::Document aJsonDocument;
aJsonDocument.SetObject();
rapidjson::Document::AllocatorType &aAllocator = aJsonDocument.GetAllocator();

rapidjson::Value aPsmJson(rapidjson::kStringType);
std::string aStr = "ABCDEF";
aPsmJson.SetString(aStr.c_str(), aAllocator);
aJsonDocument.AddMember("value", aPsmJson, aAllocator);

//jsonToString is a function to convert json document to string
std::string aInputJsonString = jsonToString(aJsonDocument);
std::cout << "Output: " << aInputJsonString ;
```

This is giving output
{"value":"ABCDEF"}

Comment: I have to send the std::string to a URI. The std string will contain the message like { "data":{

           "value": "AB1234"
        }
}   So i was forming the json object and trying to convert it into std::string.

Comment: So, problem solved?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You forgot to create a `Value` for `"data"`:

```
string s = "ABCDEF";
Document d(kObjectType);
Value data(kObjectType);
Value value;
value.SetString(s.c_str(), d.GetAllocator());
data.AddMember("value", value, d.GetAllocator());
d.AddMember("data", data, d.GetAllocator());

std::cout << jsonToString(d);
```

Output:

```
{
    "data": {
        "value": "ABCDEF"
    }
}
```